# I've taken a working CSS animation (text-typing effect) and nested it in a parent div. This small edit completely breaks it. Help me understand why?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-animations

I'm working on a small game site for a friend's birthday and I'm trying to create a typing-text effect using CSS animations by following an example provided at [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/) site. Basically, it changes the width of the text element, step-by-step, from 0 to 100%, to reveal the text. It also uses a blink animation to create a cursor. The example even provides a codepen to play around with.

I was able to recreate the effect successfully with some modifications that I wanted. However, I also want to stick the whole thing inside of a div, but when I try to do this, Irun into a problem. Instead of the text scrolling effect going to the end of the text and the text staying centered, the animation now goes the full width of the parent element and the text gets pushed all the way to the left! I don't know why this would be happening. I've tried to figure out what might be causing the issue and the only thing I've been able to learn is that when the animation is disabled, the text displays correctly (centered).

If you look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/UncaughtDanError/pen/JjLqJEv), you can see the effect I'm going for.  Here's is the code:

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  padding-top: 5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.typewriter h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s steps(30, end),
    blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: orange }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
  <h1>The cat and the hat.</h1>
</div>
```

And this [codepen](https://codepen.io/UncaughtDanError/pen/mdxYwMY) has my small edit to the example.

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  padding-top: 5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 300px;
  width: 75%;
}

.typewriter h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s steps(30, end),
    blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: orange }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">  
  <div class="typewriter">
    <h1>The cat and the hat.</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm at a loss here.  Can anyone help me understand what the issue might be from such a small edit and how I might fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference are the styles on the parent container which is `body` in the first case, therefore should be on `.main` in the second case.

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  padding-top: 5em;
}

.main {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 300px;
  width: 75%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.typewriter h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(30, end), blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
}


/* The typing effect */

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}


/* The typewriter cursor effect */

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: orange
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="typewriter">
    <h1>The cat and the hat.</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I know it was something simple, but for some reason I just wasn't seeing it.  Thank you!